# All the links in the same row

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm doing a database where it has 2 columns: event_name and event_URL. It doesn't get the name and puts all the urls on the event_URL column. Print: https://prnt.sc/fru1tr

Code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import psycopg2

page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.meetup.com/find/outdoors-adventure/?allMeetups=false&radius=50&userFreeform=London%2C+&mcId=c1012717&change=yes&sort=default')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

events = soup.find('ul', class_='j-groupCard-list searchResults tileGrid tileGrid--3col tileGrid_atMedium--2col tileGrid_atSmall--1col')

A = []
B = []

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='meetup' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='root'")
except:
    print 'Unable to connect to the database.'

cur = conn.cursor()

for event in events.findAll('li'):
    text = event.findAll('h3')
    if len(text) != 0:
        A.append(text[0].find(text = True))
    url = event.find('a', href=True)
    if len(url) != 0:
        B.append(url['href'])
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO outdoors_adventure(event_name,event_url) VALUES(%s,%s)""", (tuple(A),tuple(B)))
    conn.commit()
    del A[:]
    del B[:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the indentation is right in the posted code, the problem might be in the nested for-loop: for every event, you append the "B" list with **all the links** on the page. You could try:

```
for event in events.findAll('li'):
    text = event.findAll('h3')
    if len(text) != 0:
        A.append(text[0].find(text = True))
for link in events.findAll('li'):
    url = link.find('a', href=True)
    if len(url) != 0:
        B.append(url['href'])
```

Or better, keep the event-name and event-URL search in a single for-loop, fetching first the text and then the url of *event*

*EDIT:* You can simplify the name extraction, by using:

```
for event in events.findAll('li'):
    text = event.h3.string.strip()
    if len(text) != 0:
        A.append(text)
    url = event.find('a', href=True)
    ...
```

Let me know if that does the trick for you (it does on my side).

*EDIT2:* The problem might be just the fact that the extracted string starts with tabs (maybe that's why your DB seems "not to show the name" - its there, but you only see the tabs in the preview?). Just use `strip()` to remove them.

Comment: It inserts the name of the event but you can't see it. Thanks ;)

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: No, strip() works out the box, the rest is BeautifulSoup

Comment: But the problem is with '.string'

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the previous comment. I double checked the code [link](https://pastebin.com/Z14hf34D) and it works fine for me

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: That error means that there is nothing fulfilling the criteria. Which should not be the case on the page you mention in your code.

Comment: How can I fix it then?